# Can every Borel set be written as a disjoint union of elements in the algebra of half open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know that the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. Is it true that every Borel set $A \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of elements in $\mathcal{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take the rationals $\Bbb{Q}$

It is a countable union of closed sets(thus Borel),but it cannot be expressed as a countable disjoint union of finite disjoint unions of half-open intervals because then it would have non-empty interior.(which of course cannot be the case)

Comment: But aren't you able to produce singletons via intersections? Intersections can be represented as unions of complements. Hence, a countable union of singletons will give you $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @FredericChopin you ask specifically for unions..an i answred that cannot every Borel set be a countable UNION of elements of $A$..

Comment: Sorry, even though the algebra is closed under finite intersections, this means that there won't be any singletons in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: So just to add, an example of a uncountable set that cannot be written as a disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ is a fat Cantor set because it has empty interior (it also has positive measure). Is this correct?

Comment: @FredericChopin i believe it is..because in a union of half open intervals you can find a small open interval inside a half open..