# Is a probability measure completely determined by its values on intervals?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

While reading [Robert Ash's Basic Probability Theory](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPTCh2.pdf), I saw the following theorem (p.53):

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$, with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$. There is a unique probability measure $P$ on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $P(I)=\int_If(x)\,dx$ for all intervals $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is this: If there is no such density function $f(x)$, then is it possible that a probability measure on Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is not completely determined by its values on intervals?

Comment: Since the Borel subsets are generated by the intervals, it is sufficient to specify them on intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite disjoint unions of ingtervals of the type $[a,b)$ form an algebra which generates the Borel sigma algebra. This implies that if two probability measures agree on intervals they agree on all Borel sets.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement "Finite disjoint unions of intervals of the type [a,b) form an algebra which generates the Borel sigma algebra" ? Thank you.

Comment: That is quite standard. A good reference for that is Section 8$ in Halmos's 'Measure Theory'.  @ashpool

Comment: Thanks. I read it. But the section you referred to makes no mention of Borel sigma algebra. Are you saying that every Borel set is a countable union of disjoint half-open intervals? This post says otherwise: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462061/can-every-borel-set-be-written-as-a-disjoint-union-of-elements-in-the-algebra-of

Comment: Sigma algebra generated by a family of sets is an abstract concept;you cannot write down all sets in it explicitly in terms of the original family of sets. I am only saying that the sigma algebra generated by half closed intervals coincides with the Borel sigma algebra but nobody knows how  a general Borel set looks like.

Comment: If the half-open intervals are not disjoint, then one can't use the countable additivity of probability measure, so I don't see why two probability measures agreeing on intervals agree on every Borel set...

Comment: It is a  non-trivial fact that if two probability measures agree on an algebra they agree on the sigma algebra generated. You cannot prove this in one line using just countbale additivity.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!